# How could I make my PIC32CXMTG-EK send messages to the electrical network through PLC without needing a request from my Circutor concentrator?

Tags: pic, microchip, plc

My scenario:

- PIC32CXMTG-EK Evaluation Kit
- PL460 Evaluation Kit
- Compact DC-S SBT, PRIME PLC Concentrator

Relevant information about it:

- The main protocol in use for communication is DLSM-COSEM.
- The PIC32 and the Circutor concentrator are communicating through PLC technology. The PIC32 is directly connected to the PL460 (which acts as PLC) and the Circutor concentrator has its own PLC integrated.
- The PIC32 is acting as server and the Circutor concentrator is acting as client.
- The PIC32 uses binaries to run which are coded in C. I can modify the code using IAR EW for Arm 9.40.1 and compile new binaries to use.

What I've already achieved:

- Making simple requests from the Circutor concentrator such as asking for parameters already configured in the PIC32. I am able to view the results in the Circutor web app.

What I want to achieve:

- The same I've already achieved, but without requests. In essence, making the PIC32 send information (no matter how simple it is) without making previous requests through the Circutor. Kind of like broadcasting messages to the electrical network. I've been investigating about this and discovered you can use the section "The DataNotification service" from the DLSM-COSEM protocol.

Questions:

- ¿How can I achieve this broadcasting of messages? Getting a single message broadcasted this way without requests would be more than enough, but I'm lost on how to do it. How could I do it? Is there code for this task out there? How could I check that It's working? Will PRIME Manager sniffer be enough to check results?
- Is the Circutor concentrator absolutely necessary to check for results?

*PS: I'm no expert on this topic in general, so any info and explanations would be greatly appreciated. If this is the wrong forum to post this, don't hesitate to point it out and I'll move the question!*